# Transformation between Left and Right Kan Extensions

Tags: ct.category-theory, reference-request

The following object has turned up in my research recently, and it would be surprising (to put it mildly) if no one else has seen, used or studied it before. I am hoping for a name and some references with basic properties, if these already exist.

### Setup

Start with a full subcategory $A$ of a category $B$ and a functor $F:A \to \text{Vect}$. By full subcategory category I mean that every $B$-morphism between two objects of $A$ is also an $A$-morphism, and by $\text{Vect}$ I mean the category of vector spaces over some fixed field with linear maps as morphisms. In general, one could replace the target of $F$ by anything that has limits and colimits. Here is the picture:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \stackrel{F}{\longrightarrow} & \text{Vect} \\\\
\downarrow & ~ & \\\\
B & ~ & ~
\end{array}
$$

### Two Extensions

Now, the left Kan extension $LF:B \to \text{Vect}$ of $F$ along the inclusion of $A$ into $B$ may be defined at any object $b \in B$ as the colimit of the diagram $F\downarrow b$. This is precisely $F$-image of all morphisms in $B$ from objects of $A$ with target $b$.

On the other hand, one has the right Kan extension $RF:B \to \text{Vect}$ defined dually. In this case, we use the limit of the diagram $b \downarrow F$, which consists of $F$-images of morphisms in $B$ from $b$ to objects of $A$.

Since $A$ is full in $B$, it is well-known that both $RF$ and $LF$ will make the above diagram commute on the nose rather than requiring any non-trivial natural transformations, etc.

### The Object

Clearly -- using the fact that $A$ is full -- every object $a$ in the diagram $F \downarrow b$ has arrows to every object $a'$ in $b \downarrow F$ arising from the $F$-image of the compositions $a \to b \to a'$ in $B$. By universal properties of limits and colimits, this induces a unique linear map $LF(b) \to RF(b)$ for each $b \in B$ and in fact produces a natural transformation $\eta:LF \Rightarrow RF$ between Kan Extensions.

> What is $\eta$ called, and are there any references to it as well as its properties?

Comment: In your first and second paragraph on "Two Extensions" $LK$ and $RK$ should probably be $LF$ and $RF$ respectively. Moreover, I do not see where you need the assumption that the category is thin (BTW, I do prefer term "degenerated"), a you can construct you $\eta$ by the following natural isomorphism (applied in the reversed order to the identity on $F$; $J\colon \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ stays here for the inclusion):
$$\hom(\int^A(\hom(J(A),-)\times F(A), \int_B F(B)^{\hom(-, J(B))})$$
by the definition of the object of natural trnasformations:


Comment: $$\int_C \hom(\int^A(\hom(J(A),C)\times F(A), \int_B F(B)^{\hom(C, J(B))})$$
 the preservation of ends and coend:
$$\int_{A,B,C} \hom(\hom(J(A),C)\times F(A), F(B)^{\hom(C, J(B))})$$
by currying and preservation of ends:
$$\int_{A,B} \hom(F(A)\times\int^C \hom(J(A),C) \times \hom(C, J(B)) , F(B))$$
by Yoneda:
$$\int_{A,B} \hom(F(A)\times \hom(J(A), J(B)), F(B))$$
by preservation of ends and fully-faithfulness of $J$:
$$\int_{B} \hom(F(B), F(B))$$
 

Comment: In the first sentence under the heading "The Object", you refer to $F(b)$.  What does that mean, considering that $b$ is an object of $B$ while the domain of $F$ is only $A$?

Comment: Andreas, should be fixed now I think. Michal, thank you for commenting but I am unfamiliar with your notation: what are those integral signs?

Comment: @Vidit, $\int^A$ denotes coend, and $\int_A$ denotes end.

Comment: @Vidit and @Michal: There is an equivalent but less notation-heavy way to construct the morphism in question. If $f_!$ denotes left Kan extension along $f$, and $f_\ast$ denotes right Kan extension, then we have adjunctions $f_! \dashv f^\ast \dashv f_\ast$. Here, $L \dashv R$ means $L$ is left adjoint to $R$. From those adjunctions, we conclude that a morphism $f_! X \to f_\ast X$ as in the question is the same as (1) a morphism $X\to f^\ast f_\ast X$, and (2) a morphism $f^\ast f_! X \to X$. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) But these latter morphisms can be chosen as (1) the inverse of the counit of the adjunction $f^\ast \dashv f_\ast$, and (2) the inverse of the unit of the adjunction $f_! \dashv f^\ast$. Those morphisms are invertible as long as you assume that $f$ is full and faithful. I have not been able to prove *abstractly* that choices (1) and (2) lead to the same morphism $f_! X \to f_\ast X$, although one can check it *explicitly*, as Michal does, by using the description of Kan extensions as ends/coends.